# Finding an error in an algorithm with a loop with too many iterations to step through each one manually

Tags: python, debugging

I'm a beginner in Python (and pretty much in programming in general).  I'm currently working through Python Crash Course by Eric Matthes.  There's an exercise in there (Chapter 9, exercise 9-15, Lottery Analysis) that asks to generate two random number sets, one as a user's lottery ticket, the other as a lottery drawing, and it runs through this simulation 1,000,000 to find out how many iterations it takes to get a winning number.

```
from random import choice

def get_winning_ticket(possibilities):
    """Return a winning ticket from a set of possibilities."""
    winning_ticket = []

    # We don't want to repeat winning numbers or letters, so we'll use a
    #   while loop.
    while len(winning_ticket) < 4:
        pulled_item = choice(possibilities)

        # Only add the pulled item to the winning ticket if it hasn't
        #   already been pulled.
        if pulled_item not in winning_ticket:
            winning_ticket.append(pulled_item)

    return winning_ticket

def check_ticket(played_ticket, winning_ticket):
    # Check all elements in the played ticket. If any are not in the 
    #   winning ticket, return False.
    for element in played_ticket:
        if element not in winning_ticket:
            return False

    # We must have a winning ticket!
    return True

def make_random_ticket(possibilities):
    """Return a random ticket from a set of possibilities."""
    ticket = []
    # We don't want to repeat numbers or letters, so we'll use a while loop.
    while len(ticket) < 4:
        pulled_item = choice(possibilities)

        # Only add the pulled item to the ticket if it hasn't already
        #   been pulled.
        if pulled_item not in ticket:
            ticket.append(pulled_item)

    return ticket


possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
winning_ticket = get_winning_ticket(possibilities)

plays = 0
won = False

# Let's set a max number of tries, in case this takes forever!
max_tries = 1_000_000

while not won:
    new_ticket = make_random_ticket(possibilities)
    won = check_ticket(new_ticket, winning_ticket)
    plays += 1
    if plays >= max_tries:
        break

if won:
    print("We have a winning ticket!")
    print(f"Your ticket: {new_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
    print(f"It only took {plays} tries to win!")
else:
    print(f"Tried {plays} times, without pulling a winner. :(")
    print(f"Your ticket: {new_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
```

What I wanted to do was take this and modify it so that it compares a ticket of numbers that I chose myself with the drawing, ultimately running the previous simulation and this modified one to see whether choosing your own numbers for the ticket or letting the machine randomly generate them gives you the better odds for winning.  I modified the code below, replacing new_ticket from the previous code to my_ticket with self chosen numbers (line 3 below), all other code being the same:

```
possibilities = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
winning_ticket = get_winning_ticket(possibilities)
my_ticket = [2, 7, 'c', 'e']

plays = 0
won = False

# Let's set a max number of tries, in case this takes forever!
max_tries = 1_000_000

while not won:
    #new_ticket = make_random_ticket(possibilities)
    won = check_ticket(my_ticket, winning_ticket)
    plays += 1
    if plays >= max_tries:
        break

if won:
    print("We have a winning ticket!")
    print(f"Your ticket: {my_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
    print(f"It only took {plays} tries to win!")
else:
    print(f"Tried {plays} times, without pulling a winner. :(")
    print(f"Your ticket: {my_ticket}")
    print(f"Winning ticket: {winning_ticket}")
```

I have increased the max_tries up to 1_000_000_000 and run this a whole bunch of times, not once getting the winning number with the numbers I've chosen (it only takes anywhere from a few hundred up to a few thousand tries get it when randomly generated.  I've also tried defining the my_ticket variable in different places, with the same result (or lack thereof).  I'm not the most statistically inclined person, but something seems wrong here and I'm thinking there's issues with this code and I'm wondering if any of you have any insight.

Also: this is my first time posting here so hopefully I formatted things correctly so it's easy to read.  Thanks!

Comment: Honestly, this would be an excellent problem for you to figure out on your own, as an exercise in debugging. :) Have Fun!

Comment: https://www.sqlshack.com/how-to-debug-python-scripts-in-visual-studio-code/

Comment: You just check the same ticket 100... times, if you do not change it in the while loop, it is unnecessary to check it multiple times.

Answer (score 1):

**Problems are always diagnosed by the same scenario:**

1. **Localize the problem.** **Find the exact place in the code where the problem manifests itself.**

   - (If this was a larger system, you'd first need to localize it to a hardware or software component)
2. **Examine the program state at that moment to see which of the values it uses is wrong**
3. **Trace the wrong value back to its origin**

---

In your case,

1. is the loop. You can see (and double check with a debugger) that its input values are correct. And you already found out that its output is most likely incorrect.
2. **here, we have not a single line** that converts correct data into incorrect **but an entire chunk of algorithm that it's unclear what's happening in.** So **we need to trace its execution** to find that out.

   The easiest and most universal way to do that is **with debug printing:<sup>1</sup>** print out the input and output values involved in each algorithm's step that interests you at the moment, perhaps with comments about what operation that step does, with enough granularity for you to get an idea. E.g.:

   ```
   print(f'comparing {my_ticket} and {winning_ticket}')
   won = check_ticket(my_ticket, winning_ticket)
   print(won)
   ```
3. This should instantly show you that you're comparing the same values in each iteration, over and over again. So the logic that picks the values for comparison is the culprit.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>The next most popular technique is with a debugger tracepoint (which does the same but without altering the program). AFAICS, Python's `pdb` does not support tracepoints though.</sub>

Answer (score -1):

```
while not won:
    #new_ticket = make_random_ticket(possibilities)
    won = check_ticket(my_ticket, winning_ticket)
    plays += 1
    if plays >= max_tries:
        break
```

This loop checks `my_ticket` over and over.  It never changes.  It's always the same ticket.

So if it didn't win on the first loop, it will **never** win, and this loop uselessly runs until it reaches max_tries.